# What is an active Indie iOS development community?

Tags: ios

I've just gotten into iOS development, and would love to develop some games, but need inspiration/support, all that stuff a great community gives you.

Does anyone know of a community to get involved with?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say check out the [cocos2d forums](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/). They are really active and supportive. There is also [iDevGames](http://www.idevgames.com/).

Comment: If you ask the right questions, this place and StackOverflow can be pretty useful. I find most of my coding questions aren't iOS specific.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a specifically iOS forum, but try [Gamedev.net](http://gamedev.net/community). They are friendly and [very] active. (Unless you act like a moron)